# GoogleAppEngine: ResourceContainer class definition

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Trying to understand how to create a request class in GoogleAppEngine

Using example in Udacity "Developing Scalable Apps in Python".

In lesson 2, in order to specify a request class, the e.g uses the following class definition

```
REQUEST_CONTAINER = endpoints.ResourceContainer(
    message_types.VoidMessage,
    name=messages.StringField(1),
)
```

1. What are the first and second arguments that are given into class initializer

   - Is the first argument, the content of the message body.  In this case, it is set to Null since there will be no message body
   - Is the second argument what will be there in the GET request after the url (for e.g: http:///)
2. Why is there a *,*(comma) after the second argument.  I.e why doesn't it just end with a close bracket ")"

Comment: On the comma question have a look at python syntax docs.  It is optional and valid for lists and argument lists to have a trailing ','

Comment: Thx for the input on the comma.  Why so many options?!! :)

Comment: Its actually very convenient.  I almost always leave a trailing comma, it means when you add something it's always there.  Also the trailing comma "," is required when you want to create a single element tuple. e.g (x,)  otherwise it is interpreted as (x) in in the scope of the bracket - ie expression.  This is just python of course and nothing to do with appengine.